# How to install local npm automatically?

Tags: node.js, npm

I developed an application in `NodeJS` which use external `npm` which are not published on `npm`.

I've actually separated my code in components, so the app have this structure:

```
/app
    index.js
/components
    /componentA
        index.js
    /componentB
        index.js
```

so essentially when I publish the app on my server, I did:

```
npm i
npm i ../components/componentA
npm i ../components/componentB
```

as you can see this could be problematic if the `app` is a big project and have hundreds of components. So my question is, how can I execute a script that check automatically if the components are installed and automatically install it?

I want avoid service like `bit.dev` or something like. I also used `npm link` but unfortunately when I install a new package my own `npm` are automatically removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a package.json in your project, you can run `npm i -S ../components/componentA` which will add it as a dependency in your package.json.

Your package.json should look like

```
"dependencies": {
  "componentA": "file:../components/componentA",
  "componentB": "file:../components/componentB"
}
```

On server just run `npm i` to get these components installed

Comment: Interesting, is possible specifiy the dependency through terminal or should I set this manually?

Comment: It can and should be done through the terminal by executing  `npm install --save ../components/componentA`. This will update your package,json